# How to determine a request's real serverPort when a Host header is present

Tags: java, http, spring-security, servlet-3.0

I have a spring boot application with management endpoints enabled.
That means the application starts on port 8080, the management endpoints are available on port 8081.

The application is secured using spring security, however, the management endpoints should be accessible without authentication. So I added a request matcher that evaluates the server port (using `request.getServerPort()`) to ignore all requests to the management endpoints on port 8081.

Now it happens that when a `Host` header is present, the port of this header is returned in `request.getServerPort()`, and not the real server port.

That means I could access the application using a `Host` header with port 8081 and bypass Spring Security!?

Examples for clarity:

```
curl localhost:8080
returns 401 (unauthorized, that's correct)

curl localhost:8081/health
returns 200 (found)
```

but

```
curl -H "Host: localhost:8081" localhost:8080
returns 200 (wtf?) - because request.getServerPort() == 8081

curl -H "Host: localhost:8080" localhost:8081/health
returns 401 - because request.getServerPort() == 8080
```

The question is: how can I determine the real port where the application is receiving a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ServletRequest#getLocalName() returns local hostname.
ServletRequest#getLocalAddr() returns local IP.
ServletRequest#getLocalPort() returns local port.
```

for more clarity, please refer: 
[Get Application Server name or ip and port in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826977/get-application-server-name-or-ip-and-port-in-java)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was mislead by the debugger showing me `localPort=-1` in Tomcat's `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` instance. But now I see that the localPort will be computed if it is -1.